# UIbutton background colour and button enable/disable

Tags: swift3

How can we set a hex value to the background of button value is `#88D317`? Also, I want to keep the button enabled only if there is text present in textfields, else disabled.

Here is the code I have written:

```
class ViewControllerDonarLogin: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var btnlogin: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldpassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldusername: UITextField!

    var alert : UIAlertController = UIAlertController()
    var action : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        buttonborder()

        btnlogin.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 136/255, green: 211/255, blue: 23/255, alpha: 0.5)

        if textfieldpassword.text == "" && textfieldusername.text == "" {
            btnlogin.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            btnlogin.isEnabled = true
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the text field's `UIControl` actions.

In `viewDidLoad`, add `self` as a target for `editingChanged`:

```
textfieldpassword.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged), for: .editingChanged)
textfieldusername.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged), for: .editingChanged)
```

Now, add this method:

```
func textChanged() {
    // This will be called every time the text field's text changes
}
```

Move the original code you wrote in `viewDidLoad` to the above method.

```
if textfieldpassword.text == "" || textfieldusername.text == ""
{
    btnlogin.isEnabled = false
}
else
{
    btnlogin.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: but this is only for textfieldpassword text and what about textfieldusername

Comment: @TejalOhara See the latest edit. You should also add target for textfieldusername

Comment: No it is working on either of fields if both are blank it doesnt work i have tried putting && condition

Comment: When both or either are blank you want the buttons disabled right? @TejalOhara

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve can be done by using text field delegates. You will have to use

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
     if textfieldpassword.text == "" || textfieldusername.text == "" {
        btnlogin.isEnabled = false
    } else {
        btnlogin.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

also you will have to disable the button in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    btnlogin.isEnabled = false // as you want button to be disabled at the starting 
}
```

Comment: this code doesnt enable the button after the text filelds are filed up as it is not running the else block

Comment: it will work when ur keyboard will dismiss... if you want it in starting you can write same code in func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        
    }